# CodeIgniter 3: Multiple condition in if statement not working in Php

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement

I'm new with CodeIgniter. I have an if/if else statement in my view file and the codition after || is not working

**Here's a code from my view**

```
<?php if (($destination["site"]!="block_view/profile/profile")||($destination["site"]!="block_view/profile/slips")){
?>


<section id="profilephp-header" style="background-image: url(<?php echo base_url('assets/img/parallax/header-profile.jpg'); ?>);" class="parallax">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="sec-title text-center wow animated fadeInDown">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/parallax/profile-text.png'); ?>" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php 
}else if(($destination["site"]=="block_view/profile/profile")||($destination["site"]=="block_view/profile/slips")){?>
    <section id="profilephp-header2" style="background-image: url(<?php echo base_url('assets/img/parallax/header-profile.jpg'); ?>);" class="parallax">
        <div class="overlay">

        </div>
    </section>
<?php
}?>
```

It seems like the if statement is only accepting one condition. All the conditions in my view files is like this.

Comment: But both if statements are the same? Am I missing something?

Comment: No, they are not, but seeing the statements, `$destination["site"]` can only have one value wich is either not `"block_view/profile/profile"` **or** not `"block_view/profile/slips"` so this `if` statement is always `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$destination['site']` has one value, but in your first if-statement, you're checking if it's either not equal to one thing, or it's not equal to another thing. That'll always be true!

It looks like you were intending to show that section if the destination site was neither of those, so you could rewrite it as this:

```
<?php if (!in_array($destination['site'], ['block_view/profile/profile', 'block_view/profile/slips'])): ?>
<section id="profilephp-header" style="background-image: url(<?php echo base_url('assets/img/parallax/header-profile.jpg'); ?>);" class="parallax">
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="sec-title text-center wow animated fadeInDown">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/parallax/profile-text.png'); ?>" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<?php else: ?>
    <section id="profilephp-header2" style="background-image: url(<?php echo base_url('assets/img/parallax/header-profile.jpg'); ?>);" class="parallax">
        <div class="overlay">

        </div>
    </section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It works! thank you so much. I understand it now, thanks for explaining it.

Answer (score 3):

As I said in my comment, `$destination["site"]` is always either

- *not `"block_view/profile/profile"`*
  **or**
- *not `"block_view/profile/slips"`*
  so your `if` statement is always `true`.

You might want to write

```
if (($destination["site"]!="block_view/profile/profile")&&($destination["site"]!="block_view/profile/slips"))
```

instead of

```
if (($destination["site"]!="block_view/profile/profile")||($destination["site"]!="block_view/profile/slips"))
```

(replace `||` - OR - with `&&` - AND)

---

Addition to my answer :

You seemed - as per your question - to believe that `!a || !b` is the same as `!(a || b)`.

You have to know that when you negate a big statement like this, you have to revert `&&` and `||` operands as you distribute the negation.

Basic example :

- I want to find a sock which is not red or blue (`!(red || blue)`)
  is the same as
- I want to find a sock which is neither red nor blue (`!red && !blue`)

Answer (score 0):

replace your `<?php if (($destination["site"]!="block_view/profile/profile")||($destination["site"]!="block_view/profile/slips")){
    ?>` with `&&` condition you might got confused with the two.